# Inherit variables within a callable

Tags: php, closures

Is there any way to access values from within an an anonymous function without having to use `use()`?

```
$scope->name = "Billy";

$scope->sayHi = function(){
    echo "Hello $scope->name";
};
```

I have this method in the `$scope` class and it works because of the `bindTo()`, but I have to use `$this` instead of `$scope`, is there any way that I can make it use `$scope` instead?

```
public function __call($name, $arguments){
    if(isset($this->properties[$name])){
        $call = $this->properties[$name];
        $call = $call->bindTo($this);
        call_user_func_array($call, $arguments);
    }
}
```

The result that works without using `$scope`:

```
$scope->name = "Billy";

$scope->sayHi = function(){
    echo "Hello $this->name";
};
```

Comment: what's wrong with use?  also what's wrong with injecting it as a parameter.

Comment: Because using `$this` is visually a little more confusing than `$scope`.

Comment: Wel'll using `$this` in a closure only works in PHP 5.4 and up, just saying.  What's wrong with `use( $scope)` exactly?